# How to insert json data in table

Tags: jquery, tablerow

I want  to insert json data in html table. But I cannot. what am I doing wrong?

In every text-box I get object written to JSON data:

```
{ 
    invoice_no    : "27745186", 
    line_itemID   : "1", 
    supplier_name : "Dell", 
    supplier_id   : "", 
    description   : "asdsadas adsdsadasd sadasdadada dsa…", 
    serial_no     : "", 
    asset_type    : "", 
    asset_typeID  : "0", 
    assetSubtype  : "", 
    manufacturer  : "", 
    // ... 79 more
}
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
var rowdt = Inv_dt.length;
jQuery("#example1 tr:last").after(generateRows(rowdt));
jQuery.each(Inv_dt, function(key, value){
    jQuery("#example1 table input, select").each(function(){
        this.value = value;
        console.log(value);
        console.log(this.name);
    });
})
```

and how to extract salesTaxvalue string in regex?

```
input_[2][SALESTAXVALUE]
input_[3][SALESTAXVALUE]
select_[3][SALESTAXVALUE]
```

Comment: post you json Data, good if you create http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Why you remove your code ? its difficult for others or future user to understand it,

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried, am assuming your JSON data would be like

```
var objData = [{
    invoice_no: "27745186",
    line_itemID: "1",
    supplier_name: "Dell",
    supplier_id: "",
    description: "asdsadas adsdsadasd sadasdadada dsa…",
    serial_no: "",
    asset_type: "",
    asset_typeID: "0",
    assetSubtype: "",
    manufacturer: "",

}, {
    invoice_no: "245186",
    line_itemID: "1",
    supplier_name: "HP",
    supplier_id: "",
    description: "sdadada dsa…",
    serial_no: "",
    asset_type: "",
    asset_typeID: "0",
    assetSubtype: "",
    manufacturer: "",

}];
```

If so then this will generate table 
    $("button").on('click', function () {

```
    var aTable = $("#tb_Demo");
    $.each(objData, function (indx) {
        var col1 = objData[indx].supplier_name;
        var col2 = objData[indx].invoice_no;
        var col3 = objData[indx].description;
        var elTROW = '<tr><td>' + col1 + '</td><td>' + col2 + '</td><td>' + col3 + '</td></tr>';
        $(aTable).append(elTROW);
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7vkec7tj/5/)**

Comment: thanks for reply but you have added 3 key explicitly "supplierName",InoviceNo and description i have 90 columns like this so i don't want to do explicit i want to extract from string its key name 
can u help me out in 
extracting salesTaxvalue string in regex?

input_[2][SALESTAXVALUE]

Comment: Yes i added explicitly 3 cols, you can do it  dynamically by getting column count and do for loop over it,

Comment: Also what is `input_[2][SALESTAXVALUE]` ,  seems its incomplete post, do add relevant code in it

Comment: input_[2][SALESTAXVALUE] this is string and i want to extract salestaxvalue how would i do it